# Leopard => Snow Leopard architecture woes with nokogiri / rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nokogiri, 32bit-64bit, libxml2, osx-snow-leopard

I'm confused. It's a regular state of affairs for me but specifically in this case I felt I could reach out to fellow stackoverflowers (that is, stackoverflow-ers, not stackover-flowers).

```
uname -a
Darwin macbookpro 10.3.0 Darwin Kernel Version 10.3.0: Fri Feb 26 11:58:09 PST 2010; root:xnu-1504.3.12~1/RELEASE_I386 i386

set

bash-3.2$ set
...
HOSTTYPE=x86_64
...
MACHTYPE=x86_64-apple-darwin10.0
...
```

I'm having a nightmare rebuilding some native ruby gems and I'm wondering whether this is part of the problem -- part of this machine says its 64 bit but another part 32 ... as far as I can tell?

Under 'About this Mac' it says 'Intel Core 2 Duo' which Apple says is 64 bit. So why, after doing

```
sudo gem pristine --all
```

am I still getting this kind of error?

```
dlopen(/Applications/Rails/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/nokogiri-1.4.2/lib/nokogiri/nokogiri.bundle, 9): no suitable image found.  Did find:
 /Applications/Rails/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/nokogiri-1.4.2/lib/nokogiri/nokogiri.bundle: mach-o, but wrong architecture - /Applications/Rails/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/nokogiri-1.4.2/lib/nokogiri/nokogiri.bundle
```

Specifically I had removed nokogiri and reinstalled it. No errors in output.

```
bash-3.2$ sudo gem install nokogiri
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
Successfully installed nokogiri-1.4.2
1 gem installed
```

thanks for any thoughts!

**UPDATE**

I've found a [useful post by Chris Noos](http://chrisroos.co.uk/blog/2010-03-26-libxml2-problems-when-installing-nokogiri) on a similar problem. This is where I am:

`cd /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/nokogiri-1.4.2/`

then made a file called wem_extconf.rb:

```
require 'mkmf'
find_library('xml2', 'xmlParseDoc')
dir_config('any-string-here', '/opt/local/include', '/opt/local/lib')
find_library('xml2', 'xmlParseDoc')
```

Running `sudo web_extconf.rb` produces

```
checking for xmlParseDoc() in -lxml2... no
checking for xmlParseDoc() in -lxml2... no
```

???? But hang on, it is there:

```
$ port installed | grep libxml2.*active
libxml2 @2.7.7_0+universal (active)

$ ls -l /opt/local/lib | grep libxml2
-rwxr-xr-x   2 root  admin  2623276 31 May 20:09 libxml2.2.dylib
-rw-r--r--   2 root  admin  3643928 31 May 20:09 libxml2.a
lrwxr-xr-x   1 root  admin       15 31 May 20:09 libxml2.dylib -> libxml2.2.dylib
-rwxr-xr-x   2 root  admin      975 31 May 20:09 libxml2.la
```

And it does appear I have several copies of the thing -- but not sure which one port installed is using (I'm assuming given it's macports, it's /opt?)

```
$ ls -l /usr/lib | grep libxml2
lrwxr-xr-x    1 root  wheel        15 23 May 16:07 libxml2.2.7.3.dylib -> libxml2.2.dylib
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root  wheel   3758272 22 Sep  2009 libxml2.2.dylib
lrwxr-xr-x    1 root  wheel        15 23 May 16:07 libxml2.dylib -> libxml2.2.dylib

$ ls -l /usr/local/lib | grep libxml2
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root    admin  1456292 30 Oct  2009 libxml2.2.dylib
-rw-r--r--  1 root    admin  4812456 30 Oct  2009 libxml2.a
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root    admin  1456292 30 Oct  2009 libxml2.dylib
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root    admin      951 30 Oct  2009 libxml2.la
```

Answer (score 1):

On Snow Leopard, `gcc` has a misleading behavior; even if you are running a i386 kernel, `gcc` will produce 64 bits binaries by default.

Have you looked at the GEM documentation to see how to specify the targeted architecture ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed the XCode Development tools?

Comment: yes thanks Toby for asking -- I installed Xcode 3.2 (the Snow Leopard version).